# Making trees(time to most recent common ancestor) along a DNA sequence

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, tikz-arrows

Hi I have a DNA sequence and i want to draw a figure that says the tree height ( time to most reason common ancestor) can change. It is a rather difficult job and I can't figure out how to draw the "trees". I have tried my best to show what i aim for and i would very much like some hints,ideas or links to similar problems. Here is my TikZ code.

```
\documentclass[report, 11pt ]{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,chains}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree} 
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows, automata, fit, shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.gates.logic.US,trees,positioning,arrows}  
\tikzset{
pics/adn/.style args={#1 and #2 style #3}{
code={
  \node[draw, fill=#1, inner sep=0pt, circle, minimum size=2mm] at       (-.3,0) (A) {};
  \node[draw, fill=#2, inner sep=0pt, circle, minimum size=2mm] at ( .3,0) (B) {};
  \draw[#3, -, shorten >=0pt, shorten <=0pt] (A) -- (B);
  \node[ellipse,draw, fit=(A) (B), inner sep=1mm] {};
}
}}



\begin{document}
\scalebox{2}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth', shorten >=1pt, node distance=.5cm,      ball/.style={draw, circle, minimum size=3mm, inner sep=0pt, fill=#1}]
\node[draw=none,fill=none] (0) {C};
\node[draw=none,fill=none, below of = 0] (1) {C};
\node[draw=none,fill=none, right of = 0] (2) {G};
\node[draw=none,fill=none, below of = 2] (3) {G};
\node[draw=none,fill=none, right of = 2] (4) {T};
\node[draw=none,fill=none, below of = 4] (5) {A};
\node[draw=none,fill=none, right of = 4] (6) {A};
\node[draw=none,fill=none, below of = 6] (7) {T};
\node[draw=none,fill=none, right of = 6] (8) {T};
\node[draw=none,fill=none, below of = 8] (9) {T};
\node[draw=none,fill=none, right of = 8] (10) {T};
\node[draw=none,fill=none, below of = 10] (11) {A};
\node[draw=none,fill=none, right of = 10] (12) {$\ldots$};
\node[draw=none,fill=none, below of = 12] (13) {$\ldots$};
 \node[draw=none,fill=none, right of = 12] (14) {A};
\node[draw=none,fill=none, below of = 14] (15) {A};

\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

This is what i am aiming for:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use the `text effects long path` to typeset the sequence and name the nodes (which is a bit of overkill, I guess) the 'trees' are typeset with a random height and a teensy bit crude:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text,calc}
\tikzset{DNA sequence/.style={decoration={
  text effects along path, text={#1},
  text effects/.cd,
    path from text, character count=\c,
    character widths={minimum width=1.5ex},
    characters={inner xsep=0, name=base-\c}
}, decorate}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path [name prefix=top-,    DNA sequence={CGTATT\ldots A}] (0,0);
\path [name prefix=bottom-, DNA sequence={CGATTA\ldots A}] (0,-.5);
\foreach \i in {1,...,6,8}
  \draw [thick, blue!50!cyan] (top-base-\i.north west) |-
    ($(0,.25+rnd)+(top-base-\i.north)$)
    -- ++(0,0.25) ++(0,-0.25) -| (top-base-\i.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice. I was looking for fixed tree heights but i think i able to do this with your code. thank you so much.